# Navbar Dropdown Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting out with web coding and I don't have much knowledge with css. I think I made some mistakes and I hope I can find a solution here. The issue is when dropdown `item` opens, "Add New" slipping sideways. How i can fix this problem? Here is my HTML an CSS code. When i write `position: absolute;` dropdown menu is dissappering too. I'm

```css
nav {
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    height: 75px;
}

nav .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
      width: 750px;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
      width: 970px;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
      width: 1170px;
    }
}

nav .logo img {
    height: 56px;
    width: 56px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

.logo {
    width: 30%;
}

.nav-items {
    display: flex;
}

.menu {
    float: right;
    
}

.menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu ul li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.menu ul li a {
    padding: 8px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-item-has-children {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu-item-has-children ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.menu-item-has-children ul li {
    float: none;
}

.menu-item-has-children ul li a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.menu-item-has-children:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

.menu-item-has-children:hover ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>NAVBAR</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="nav-first">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="nav-items">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="https://www.postakutun.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/cropped-logo-png-120p-2.png" alt="Logo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu">
                        <ul class="menu-ul">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Profile</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Security</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your dropdown `<ul>` list is pushing the the "Add New" button over to the right due to its content box size.

Comment: The problem is that the submenu occupies space. So it pushes elements inside the page when you give it ' display:block '. Try using `position:absolute` . And why do all beginners use `float:left` for layout purposes. That should be banned :) try using `flexbox` or `cssgrid` to arrange your items in the page